# Changed language, now terminal isn't working right

Tags: terminal, locale, language

- Everything *was* working fine. I could connect into the system with PuTTY, and everything would display correctly.
- I changed the language from English to Spanish using some GUI tool.
- I changed the language back to English again (i.e., everything should now be back to how it was).
- Various terminal programs no longer use the Unicode box-drawing characters any more.

  - `lsblk` now uses the verticle-pipe and backtick characters.
  - `htop` does likewise.
  - `tmux` uses rows of `x` characters (also `q` and a few others).
  - Problem appears both with and without `tmux` running.
- Output from `locale` looks the same as before.
- PuTTY has apparently set `TERM=xterm`, which has what it was before.

I'm really not sure what other settings would affect terminal rendering... but this is really driving me nuts!

Comment: Crawling through `lsblk` using GDB, it appears it uses `libsmartcols` to do the table drawing.

Comment: It seems changing `LC_CTYPE=en_GB` to `en_GB.utf8` fixes `tmux`, but not `lsblk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I *thought* the locale was still set the same... but it wasn't.

It turns out previously the locale was `en_GB.utf8`, whereas now it's just `en_GB`.

Setting this to the correct value outside of `tmux` seems to make everything behave correctly again.

A quirk is that for this to take effect *inside* `tmux`, it appears you have to *exit all sessions*, set the environment variable, and then start `tmux` again. Presumably the server itself is caching the value or something...